# React: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, backend

При попытке запустить реакт-приложение выскакивает в консоли ошибка Unexpected token '<'.
Вот package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0"}
```

Сервер:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const HOST = "localhost";
const PORT = 3000;

let server = http.createServer((req, res) => {


let stream;

switch (req.url) {
    case '/':
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8' });
        stream = fs.createReadStream('../pages/index.html').pipe(res);
        break;
    case '/index.js':
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'});
        stream = fs.createReadStream('../pages/index.js').pipe(res);
        break;
    default: 
        res.end("Page not found. Error 404.");
}})

server.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
console.log(`Server started: http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
})
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ua">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

index.js:

```
import App from "./App.js";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

И App.js:

```
function App() {
return (
    <div>
        <h1>YOOO</h1>
    </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

С проблемой вожусь уже второй день, читал про jsx, babel, но оно или не работает в моей ситуации, или я не правильно устанавливаю. Просто учусь реакту.
Скачивал обучающее реакт-приложение, оно запускается как нужно и там же в index.html нет подключения скрипта. Там только пустой код и div root. Как без подключения скрипта там может быть JS код? И как решить мою проблему?

Очень прошу помочь, тк стопит меня этот момент сильно. Я мог бы использовать стандартный старт-проект реакта, но хочу написать собственный, чтобы понять как он работает. Спасибо. Надеюсь на вас...(

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте явно указать тип скрипта в `index.html` с помощью атрибута `type`:

`<script type="module" src="./index.js" type="text/babel"></script>`

Comment: Там же указан уже тип модуль. И если просто указать тип text/babel, то страница вовсе перестанет видеть этот скрипт. Возможно стоит установить библиотеку babel, я устанавливал, но результат тот же. Возможно команды npm i babel (core, все babel пробовал устанавливать) недостаточно.